# RE2 Cleanup Vector

Tags: c++, vector, re2

as the title says I'm here with a 'little' problem regarding re2 regex and arrays. I need to load a lot of regex to test them with some strings. So I'm filling a vector. Here the first problem occurs: It it not possible to save re2::RE" Objects

> `std::vector<re2::RE2> Regex; // gives error, copy constructor or sth`

What I use is

> `std::vector<re2::RE2*> Regex;`

and allocate it dynamically.
The main problem is now the cleanup. Whether I use Raw- or Smartpointers does not matter in this case, I tested both. The Cleanup just takes forever. I'm not sure why - but it's definitely because of that regex vector.
I am loading about 1 000 000 different regex. Loading and initializing is pretty fast.

Has anyone had similar problems? Is it possible to fix that vector problem? Is there anything I can do against that Cleanup Problem?

Comment: Debug or release build? If the objects are expensive to clean up there's really not that much you can do. How long is "forever"? Are you cleaning up on exit? If so it often isn't necessary as the memory will generally be freed when you exit anyway, although I always do like to clean up when I can. You might read this and possibly search for some other articles since there are varying opinions. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/305930/if-i-need-to-use-a-piece-of-memory-throughout-the-lifespan-of-my-program-is-it

Comment: @RetiredNinja Debug and Release Build. Forever is multiple Minutes - the main program handles about 25 000 000 Objects and is terminating in <1 min. Cleanup inclusive. Just it's really just that re2 vector.